# is mod statement correct

Tags: modular-arithmetic

$2^{2n+1}$%$(2n + 1) = 1$ for all n > 1000.

I am confused to prove if it is wrong or right. As the value of n is very large.

If it is wrong then what would be the correct statement.

Comment: If $2n+1$ is prime, then $2^{2n+1}\equiv\color{red}2\bmod 2n+1$ by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem); and this is not [tag:linear-algebra]

Comment: @J.W.Tanner It is not necessary. But how you concluded that.

Answer (score -1):

No,

Counter example $n=1001$

$$2^{2n+1} \equiv 2\pmod {2n+1}$$

Comment: then what would be the correct statement.

Comment: Its never equal to $1$

Comment: I mean correct general statement.

Comment: "then what would be the correct statement."  The correct statement is it's not true.  Why should there be anything more specific than that?  If I said "Elephants are meat eaters with green feathers" and you said "No, they aren't" and I said "what would be the correct statement" what would you say?  A completely *wrong* statement isn't clear what needs to be corrected.